# How to communicate between Excel VBA and Adobe Reader XI

Tags: excel, adobe-reader, vba

Does anyone have documentation on how to communicate between a VBA macro on Excel and Adobe Reader XI? I found some information on that for Adobe Reader 9 or less, but it looks like from AR 10 or later that information is not valid anymore.

I am interested in opening a pdf file and check the different annotations in the opened pdf file.

Thank you for sharing if you have anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible, at least not with SDK options. It requires Adobe Acrobat Standard or Adobe Acrobat Pro.